# mysql strip out anything after a number appears (including the numbers)

Tags: mysql, substring

I have a query in MYSQL where it strips out anything after the following characters '.' '/' and '-' with the following code:

```
CASE

    WHEN LOCATE('.', wca.scexh.LocaLcode)>0 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(wca.scexh.LocaLcode, '.', 1)
    WHEN LOCATE('/', wca.scexh.LocaLcode)>0 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(wca.scexh.LocaLcode, '/', 1)
    WHEN LOCATE('-', wca.scexh.LocaLcode)>0 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(wca.scexh.LocaLcode, '-', 1)

    ELSE wca.scexh.LocaLcode

END as LocaLcodeNew,
```

however i would also like to add an extra case statement where it will strip anything as soon as a number appears, i tried the following case statements but does not seem to work:

```
CASE

    WHEN LOCATE('.', wca.scexh.LocaLcode)>0 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(wca.scexh.LocaLcode, '.', 1)
    WHEN LOCATE('/', wca.scexh.LocaLcode)>0 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(wca.scexh.LocaLcode, '/', 1)
    WHEN LOCATE('-', wca.scexh.LocaLcode)>0 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(wca.scexh.LocaLcode, '-', 1)
    WHEN LOCATE('0', wca.scexh.LocaLcode)>0 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(wca.scexh.LocaLcode, '0', 1)
    WHEN LOCATE('1', wca.scexh.LocaLcode)>0 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(wca.scexh.LocaLcode, '1', 1)
    WHEN LOCATE('2', wca.scexh.LocaLcode)>0 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(wca.scexh.LocaLcode, '2', 1)
    WHEN LOCATE('3', wca.scexh.LocaLcode)>0 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(wca.scexh.LocaLcode, '3', 1)
    WHEN LOCATE('4', wca.scexh.LocaLcode)>0 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(wca.scexh.LocaLcode, '4', 1)
    WHEN LOCATE('5', wca.scexh.LocaLcode)>0 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(wca.scexh.LocaLcode, '5', 1)
    WHEN LOCATE('6', wca.scexh.LocaLcode)>0 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(wca.scexh.LocaLcode, '6', 1)
    WHEN LOCATE('7', wca.scexh.LocaLcode)>0 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(wca.scexh.LocaLcode, '7', 1)
    WHEN LOCATE('8', wca.scexh.LocaLcode)>0 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(wca.scexh.LocaLcode, '8', 1)
    WHEN LOCATE('9', wca.scexh.LocaLcode)>0 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(wca.scexh.LocaLcode, '9', 1)

    ELSE wca.scexh.LocaLcode

END as LocaLcodeNew,
```

I would greatly appreciate any help on this, thanks in advance!

The following examples currently work as with the case statements i have in as i no longer see / . or - in any codes:

DOW.11 appears as DOW
DOW/11 appears as DOW
DOW-11 appears as DOW

But would also need to cater the following examples:

DOW0123 to appear as DOW
DOW2345 to appear as DOW
DOW3456 to appear as DOW

etc

Bear in mind its random letters/numbers not always the same amount of characters for each code.

Comment: Please be more specific. Show some examples of input and the expected output.

Comment: If you have something like `abc123.def`, it will just remove everything after the `.`. The rest of the tests will not be done, because `CASE` stops after the first successful `WHEN` test.

Comment: Also, if you have `abc102`, it will remove everything after `0`, because it tests for that before testing for `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CASE` performs the `WHEN` tests in order, and stops as soon as one of them matches. So if you have a later match earlier in your column, you won't strip the whole thing. Instead of testing sequentially, you need to nest your functions. Replace the `CASE` expression with this:

```
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(
          SUBSTRING_INDEX(
           SUBSTRING_INDEX(
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(
             SUBSTRING_INDEX(
              SUBSTRING_INDEX(
               SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                 SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                   SUBSTRING_INDEX(evs.sxech.Localcode, '.', 1),
                    '/', 1),
                   '-', 1),
                  '0', 1),
                 '1', 1),
                '2', 1),
               '3', 1),
              '4', 1),
             '5', 1),
            '6', 1),
           '7', 1),
          '8', 1),
         '0', 1) AS LocalLcodeNew
```

You don't need the `LOCATE()` test; if the delimiter isn't in the string, `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` returns the string unchanged.

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2bd28/1)

Comment: Sorry I couldn't apply your answer successfully to my script

Comment: Hey sorry i just re-tested and actually works, i pasted the code in wrong, thank you so much for your help, really appreciate it!